# Calling a Tornado handler in another handler

Tags: python, call, handler, tornado

I want to split a Tornado handler in two handlers. In the first handler, I want send a command to a sensor. In the second handler, I want to wait for a response from the sensor.

Is this possible? Or I can't call an handler from another? If it's possible, how I can call this second handler?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that original post was asked years ago, but since accepted answer doesn't solve the question asked, and I do believe I have the proper solution, as I had a need for it. Also, if some poor soul is Googling for the same issue, hopefully they will find this.

```
class OneHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        AnotherHandler(self.application, self.request).get(id)
```

Here you can call "AnotherHandler" from within "OneHandler"

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you've got a variant of the "chat" application.  Your best bet is to take a look at the [basic chat demo app](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py).

The basic operating idea is to have a mixin (or globals if you prefer) that has a list of connections waiting on a response, when that response is set it triggers the callbacks on the original handlers.

Comment: Yes, but I have two parts completely separate. In the first part I write a command in a DB table. This command is read from a web server that send this to sensor. The sensor write the response in a DB table and is there that begin the second part: I go to read this table and take the response. So, when I write the command in the first part, I can also close my handler, but I want that automatically start the handler that go to receive the response from the sensor.... Sorry if I'm confused...

Comment: The browser must initiate the request to the handlers.  Thus in the chat example the browser is polling the server with GET requests which either timeout or return when the callback is triggered from the other handler.

Comment: So, there isn't a way to call an handler, I don't know, like a function call? I have to call any handler directly from the browser?

Comment: Correct: A Handler is a class - it's created as part of the request process, you could simulate it but the browser would have no idea it happend to update.